# AWS ECS in multiple EC2 Instances

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-ecs

Is it possible to create a ECS that run a container in multiple EC2 instances at the same time or its necessary create 1 task for each EC2 instance?

Comment: I am unsure about the point of creating 1 task for each ec2 instance? Can you explain it descriptively?

Comment: Right now, i have 2 EC2 instances behind a ELB, and a couple of ECS task that each one run an application on one of the EC2. If i shutdown one of EC2 instances, the ECS task will run again the app on the other instance. The problem is that the app take a few minutes to start, and i need to have high availability. So i want that the apps run in all EC2 instances at the same time, and ELB redirect the user to the EC2 instance available, and if i shut down one of them...the users don't be affected

Answer (score 1):

As per the clarification by you in the comment. I believe you are looking for a solution to run a highly available application which should have multiple containers so that you won't have to face downtime when you will drain the underlying EC2 instance.

In this particular scenario, you have to use ECS service with SPREAD as task placement strategy. ECS will automatically take care of the high availability of application by placing containers on the different EC2 instance of that cluster. So, When you replace the underlying ec2 instance it will first drain all the connections to the containers which were running on that instance.

You can read more about ECS Service here:

> https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/ecs_services.html

Task Placement Strategy:

> https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/task-placement-strategies.html

Do let me know for further clarification.